# Negative Binomial GLM in R and Python - Differences in coefficients

Tags: python, r, statistics, statsmodels, glm

I'm trying to implement a negative binomial regression model in R which was originally implemented in Python with statsmodels.

In some cases, the estimated coefficients are very similar:

Python code:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import numpy as np
response = [17, 18, 10, 9, 8, 5, 6, 5, 15351, 9637, 9981, 9306, 16752, 11993, 13622, 9800]

design = np.array(
      [[1, 1, 1, 0],
      [1, 1, 1, 0],
      [1, 1, 1, 0],
      [1, 1, 1, 0],
      [1, 0, 0, 0],
      [1, 0, 0, 0],
      [1, 0, 0, 0],
      [1, 0, 0, 0],
      [1, 0, 1, 1],
      [1, 0, 1, 1],
      [1, 0, 1, 1],
      [1, 0, 1, 1],
      [1, 0, 0, 1],
      [1, 0, 0, 1],
      [1, 0, 0, 1],
      [1, 0, 0, 1]])
theta = 0.00792199771866427

sm.GLM(response, design, family=sm.families.NegativeBinomial(alpha=theta)).fit().params
```

Which gives:

```
array([ 1.79175947,  0.97496014, -0.16402993,  7.68415156])
```

And the equivalent model in R:

```
library(MASS)
response = c(17, 18, 10, 9, 8, 5, 6, 5, 15351, 9637, 9981, 9306, 16752, 11993, 13622, 9800)

design = as.data.frame(matrix(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,1 , 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), ncol = 4, byrow = F))

theta = 0.00792199771866427

coef(glm(response ~. +0, design, family = negative.binomial(theta)))
```

Which gives:

```
       V1         V2         V3         V4 
 1.7917595  0.9749601 -0.1640299  7.6841516
```

So for these two models, the estimated coefficients are very similar, down to the second decimal place. I am also fitting a reduced model dropping the second column of the model matrix, however, here the estimated coefficients are quite different between R and Python.

Python

```
sm.GLM(response, design[:, [0,2,3]], family=sm.families.NegativeBinomial(alpha=theta)).fit().params
array([ 2.32804838, -0.10095997,  7.11684136])
```

R

```
coef(glm(response ~. +0, design[, c(1,3,4)] , family = negative.binomial(theta)))
       V1        V3        V4 
2.0650897 0.3232355 7.1965690
```

Why does this occur? I have noticed this characteristic for a number of different feature sets.

Comment: it is likely how the negative binomial is parameterised . try `m = glm(response ~. +0, design[-2], family = negative.binomial(1/theta))`

Comment: Aha this solves it. Thanks!